# Modeling of interval variables in R

Tags: r, artificial-intelligence, mixed-models

Good morning, my name is Thiago and I need help in evaluating some data model:

I want to model the basic density of Eucalyptus wood according to variables such as:
Species (3 species),
Age,
Soil Type (categorical variable - 7 classes),
Soil Texture (interval variable - 3 intervals),
Altitude classes (interval variable - 5 intervals),
Precipitation,
Municipality (categorical variable) and
State (categorical variable - 3 classes).

I studied and I think of using non-linear mixed models, however I run into some problems:
The first is the interval variables because I do not know how to work with them in the model.
The second is what variables to choose for random effects, I first thought about the county and the state.

Could someone help me in some way I could take to solve this problem? Who knows mixed models are not the case, could I use some artificial intelligence technique? 
Since, currently, the presence of categorical and interval variables is common in many databases.

Thank you.

Comment: This question is not appropriate for SO. To get an idea I'd suggest looking into the methods of studies similar to yours and then reading up on the statistics in more detail before you start analysing your own data.

Comment: By "interval" I suspect you mean "ordinal"? This might be a good place to start ... (if you are reasonably confident with R?) https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ordinal/